# How to use grep in Data frame in R

Tags: r

I made text comments in CSV file into dataframe such as

```
1.Mary had a little lamb and she is sweet.
2.Robin is a great superhero.
3.batman dark knight is wonderful movie.
4.Superman series has been a disappointment.
```

I tried to use

```
grep('batman',df,value =t)
```

it is giving as

```
"Mary had a little lamb and she is sweet.\",\n\"Robin is a great superhero.\"\n\"batman dark knight is wonderful movie.\",\n\"Superman series has been a disappointment.\"
```

instead, I would like the result as

```
batman dark night is a wonderful movie
```

only the above sentence should be displayed

Comment: i am getting the same result with this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Your dataframe
df = data.frame( Text = c("Mary had a little lamb and she is sweet."
                          ,"Robin is a great superhero."
                          ,"batman dark knight is wonderful movie."
                          ,"Superman series has been a disappointment."))

# get the index which has batman in the text of your dataframe
df[grep("batman", df$Text),]
```

Outputs

```
[1] "batman dark knight is wonderful movie."
```

In `dplyr` with `grepl` (which returns not a number but a logical value)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(grepl("batman", Text))
```

Outputs

```
                                    Text
1 batman dark knight is wonderful movie.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have read the data incorrectly and `df` is just one long string instead of separate lines. Ideally, you should go back one step and read the data correctly.

You haven't shared the text file nor how you read the data into R, in such case here is a way to get the correct output in the current condition when `df` is one string.

We can split the string on `'\n'` into separate vector and use `grep` to return correct line which has the word `'batman'` in it.

```
grep('batman', strsplit(df, '\n')[[1]], value = TRUE)
#[1] "\"batman dark knight is wonderful movie.\","
```

**data**

```
df <- "Mary had a little lamb and she is sweet.\",\n\"Robin is a great superhero.\"\n\"batman dark knight is wonderful movie.\",\n\"Superman series has been a disappointment.\""
```

Answer (score 0):

We may need to add word boundary (`\\b`) to avoid any non-specific matches

```
 subset(df, grepl("\\bbatman\\b", text))
                                    text
3 batman dark knight is wonderful movie.
```

Comment: Getting only the row numbers but not text . Tried to use ```value = T``` gave same result

Comment: @d123 I used `subset` which is a `base R` function that takes logical vector for subsetting